# Widget options - where to put them?

Tags: widgets, options

I have a widget which I want to add a couple of options. The options are effectively 'global' for the widget - username and password details to a secured web service.

So in effect, wherever the widget is used the same parameters will be used.

I presume I should use an add_options_page?
Or ...

Add options on the widget itself?
Or ...

can you do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this myself by adding an options page and adding options to the database.
The functions are

```
add_option('yourpluginoption1','value');
add_option('yourpluginoption2','value');

add_action('admin_menu', 'yourplugin_menu_');

function yourplugin_menu_() {
    add_options_page('etc etc...
```